# Ember.js - multiple views on same page

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Just starting to learn Ember.js, and evaluating if it fits into my project.

I have multi page application, and on each I have different content (components) that can be reused across pages. For a simplistic approach lets consider that is is a something like Recipe blog

Main page:

- Recipes (loaded via Ember)
- Popular recipes block (loaded via Ember)
- Product reference guide block (loaded via Ember)

Single Recipe page:

- Recipe contents (simple html rendered by back end)
- Comments block (loaded via Ember)
- Product reference guide block (loaded via Ember)

Product/ingredient view:

- Product contents (simple html rendered by back end)
  Comments block (loaded via Ember)
  Product reference guide block (loaded via Ember)
- etc..

So basically I have small reusable components

1. Comments
2. Product reference guide
3. Popular recipes

I want them all to be loaded independently, and I want to include them on different pages and their position would would depend on page type. And I would like to have independent events for each of those components

Skipping through the docs, I think there are couple of solutions:

1) Use different Ember application for each of my component: [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/FMV8u/13/)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='app1-view'>
I am the App1 main view
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='app2-view'>
I am the App2 main view
</script>
```

2) Use partials (can partial be bound to controller and have actions like loadNextPage, etc?) [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/dWcUp/)

```
{{partial 'navbar'}}
{{outlet}}   
{{partial 'footer'}}
```

3) Use named outlets [Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/dWcUp/)

```
{{outlet header}}
{{outlet body}}
{{outlet navBar}}
```

4)...?

Or maybe Ember is more suited for single page apps? I do not want to use jquery ui widgets, and have that bind/unbind and dom manipulation mess.

Answer (score 0):

Use views:

> Views in Ember.js are typically only created for the following reasons:
>
> > When you need sophisticated handling of user events
> >
> > When you want to create a re-usable component

Create a view per reusable component and bind it to the right templates whenever needed.

And let Ember handle the lifecycle of views and contexts for you!

For more info, read:
http://emberjs.com/guides/views/